# Use OPTIM() to MUTATE an additional column to an existing dataframe or tibble

Tags: dataframe, function, purrr, sapply, optim

I would like to add an additional column to an existing dataframe by mutating the optimized result from the OPTIM() function.  The code works when I strip the dataframe down to 1 row, but gives the following error when there are 2 rows:

Caused by error in `optim()`:
! objective function in optim evaluates to length 2 not 1

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)


hfcn <- function(b, D, U, U2, U3){
            Din = ((1 - D)^-b - 1) / b
            rsd_2 = ((U / (1 + b*Din*2)^(1/b) - U2)^2)^0.5
            rsd_3 = ((U / (1 + b*Din*3)^(1/b) - U3)^2)^0.5
            rst_tot = rsd_2 + rsd_3
            return(rst_tot)
          }

#################################
####   If I create dataframe A with a single row, the code works, but fails when there are 2 rows ####

# A <- data.frame(ID = c("A1")
#                 , U = c(28844)
#                 , D = c(0.7941582)
#                 , U2 = c(3417)
#                 , U3 = c(2465)
#                 )
#################################

A <- data.frame(ID = c("A1", "A2")
                , U = c(72625, 28844)
                , D = c(0.7785440, 0.7941582)
                , U2 = c(7916, 3417)
                , U3 = c(5409, 2465)
                )



A2 <- mutate(A
             , C = optim(par = 1.1
                          , hfcn
                          , D = A$D
                          , U = A$U
                          , U2 = A$U2
                          , U3 = A$U3
                          , method = "BFGS"
                          #, method = "L-BFGS-B"#, lower = 0, upper = 3
                        )[1]
             )
```

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `C = ...[]`.
Caused by error in `optim()`:
! objective function in optim evaluates to length 2 not 1
Backtrace:

1. dplyr::mutate(...)
2. stats::optim(...)

I have successfully run the code when I limit the database to a single row.  I can run both rows independently through the function and mutate and additional column using OPTIM(), so the code and function inputs check out.  I suspect I may have to use a function from purrr but I cannot find anything online that helps me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

You need to pass these values row-wise to `optim` and not the entire vector:

```
A2 <- A %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(C = optim(par = 1.1
                   , hfcn
                   , D = D
                   , U = U
                   , U2 = U2
                   , U3 = U3
                   , method = "BFGS"
                   #, method = "L-BFGS-B"#, lower = 0, upper = 3
  )[1]
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Note, in the tidyverse when you reference a variable you do not need to use `$`, as references are understood to be from the data frame, unless specified otherwise.

**Long answer**

When you pass your function a vector of arguments it will return a value for each set of constants (so your function is *vectorized*):

```
hfcn(b = c(.5, .5), 
     U = c(72625, 28844), 
     D = c(0.7785440, 0.7941582), 
     U2 = c(7916, 3417), 
     U3 = c(5409, 2465))
[1] 2654.797 2043.005
```

However you are trying to find an optima. So you need to set those values to be constant one set at a time:

```
optim(par = 1.1, 
      hfcn, 
      D = 0.7785440,
      U = 72625,
      U2 = 7916, 
      U3 = 5409, 
      method = "BFGS"
)
```

You are passing the arguments as a vector, but `optim` is not vectorized. It will not find the optima for each set of constants (e.g., `hfcn(U = 72625, D = 0.7785440, U2 = 7916, U3 = 5409)` then `hfcn(U = 28844, D = 0.7941582, U2 = 3417, U3 = 2465)`)-- this is what the error is saying:

```
optim(par = 1.1, 
      hfcn, 
      D = c(0.7785440, 0.7941582),
      U = c(72625, 28844),
      U2 = c(7916, 3417), 
      U3 = c(5409, 2465), 
      method = "BFGS"
)
Error in optim(par = 1.1, hfcn, D = c(0.778544, 0.7941582), U = c(72625,  : 
  objective function in optim evaluates to length 2 not 1
```

This is likely why it worked when you only did one row of data. If you had three rows you would get the same error but it would say `evaluates to length 3 not 1`.

**Additional notes**

The above code returns `C` as list-column, which is not usually what is expected. So you might try:

```
A2 <- A %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(C = unlist(optim(par = 1.1, 
                          hfcn,
                          D = D, 
                          U = U, 
                          U2 = U2,
                          U3 = U3, 
                          method = "BFGS")[1])
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

  ID        U     D    U2    U3     C
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A1    72625 0.779  7916  5409 0.805
2 A2    28844 0.794  3417  2465 1.11
```

Also depending on the size of your data set, `rowwise` is very inefficient so it could take some time to run. This is normally combatted by transforming your data into a long-format and not using `rowwise`.

Comment: LMc, Thank you for answer my query correctly and quickly!  I have been struggling with implementing functions like uniroot(), optim(), and nls() for a while now; this particular problem has had me frustrated and stumped for 3 days or more.  A simple 12 character code modification was all it took, thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again LMc, I voted up and accepted the excellent explanation.  Thanks!